# some order by in doctrine query language

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a query as below :

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, count(i.id) FROM Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Tags t
LEFT JOIN t.items i WITH i.status=1 AND (SELECT count(img.id) FROM Acme\TestBundle\Entity\ItemsImages img WHERE img.item=i.id) > 0
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY COUNT (i.id) DESC
```

This query works fine without ORDER BY clause. Whenever I add this clause it gives me error :

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 297: Error: Expected end of string, got '('
```

ORDER BY works with column names but with columns like count(i.id) is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To order by an aggregated value, you need to `SELECT` it first and then use it to `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT
    t.id,
    t.name,
    count(i.id) AS tags_count
FROM 
    Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Tags t
...
ORDER BY
    tags_count DESC
```